# position element with right property

Tags: css

I want to position one element with left in percentage and another element with left in percentage, but it does not work. Could you help me and say in details why it is not working ? Thank you

```
<div class="header" >
    <span  style="left:2.34%;z-index: 1;">MALISIMMO</span>
    <div  style="position: absolute; width: 294px; right: 1%;">
        <button   style="height: 36px;z-index: 1;">Buy</button>
        <button   style="height: 36px;z-index: 1;">About Us</button>
        <button class="position1" style="z-index: 1;">SIGN IN</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

The jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/flamant/mopu087v/9/

Comment: add position:relative to it

Comment: I added position: relative to the container and it works. But why it does not work when I put position: absolute on the container

Comment: not the container but the element where you apply the left property

Comment: Can you explain me why it does not work with position absolute on the elements I put left and right. Furthermore, I changed the width of container to 100% and the right positioned element does not react as intended

Comment: I finally found the solution. See the fiddle